# initializing char array with space(#32) not null(#0)

Tags: delphi

i use delphi 2010. i need to fill the char array with spaces not nulls. i used following code which doesn't work.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  aCharArray: array[0..9] of Char;
begin
  FillChar(aCharArray, sizeof(aCharArray), #32); // doesn't work
  FillChar(aCharArray, sizeof(aCharArray), ' '); // doesn't work

  Caption := aCharArray;
end;
```

the caption is printed with strange crosses. in an array of ansichar it works well.

please let me know the reason and the solution.

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`FillChar` is mis-named in Unicode Delphi. It should really be named `FillAnsiChar`. So you are filling the string with UTF-16 characters having ordinal value `$2020`, aka [U+2020 (DAGGER), †](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2020/index.htm).

Instead you should use [`StringOfChar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StringOfChar):

```
Caption := StringOfChar(' ', 10);
```